# Multiple LIKE comparisons in MySQL query? - MySQL, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I have a search form field that I want to compare with multiple columns within a table e.g.:

```
+----------+-------+---------+------+------------+
| name     | owner | species | sex  | birth      |
+----------+-------+---------+------+------------+
| Claws    | Gwen  | cat     | m    | 1994-03-17 |
| Bowser   | Diane | dog     | m    | 1989-08-31 |
| Whistler | Gwen  | cat     | m    | 1997-12-09 |
+----------+-------+---------+------+------------+
```

The query I made has multiple LIKE comparisons however it only seems to find rows of data for the first two columns.

The first comparison is "**name**" then "**owner**" then "**species**" then "**sex**".

It only finds rows if you enter a string that matches the first two columns, however if you enter a string that matches one of the last columns it does not return anything.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM contact 
WHERE name LIKE \"%$search%\" 
OR owner LIKE \"%$search%\"
OR species LIKE \"%$search%\" 
OR sex LIKE \"%$search%\" 
GROUP BY name, owner,species, sex
```

My only guess is that MySQL perhaps limits how many "**OR**"s you can use?

My query should return a row from the table if the string entered by the user matches any column data.

Here is my PHP code for it

```
include("database.class.php");

    //search string assigned from POST field
    $search = $_POST['contact_search'];

    $db = new database();

    $db->select('quote_system');

    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE name LIKE \"%$search%\" OR owner LIKE \"%$search%\" OR species LIKE \"%$search%\" OR sex LIKE \"%$search%\" GROUP BY name, second_name, owner, species, sex");

    print_r($result);

    while ($row = $db->fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo $row['name'];
        echo $row['owner'];
        echo $row['species'];
        echo $row['sex'];
        echo "<br/>";

    }
```

Incase theres any confusion here are some examples to show the problem:

> User enters string "claws" --> string matches data in "name" column --> prints row that column is in
>
> User enters string "m" --> string only matches data in "sex" column --> nothing shows!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Just a tip. Don't do this. Your queries have no indexes to use, meaning full table scanes *several times*.

Comment: @Layke - im a beginner, what should I do then?

Comment: There is no limit on OR, and your query should work. However, your PHP example contains a totally different query than your first example (company_name instead of species etc). Try printing your SQL before executing it, you'll see what's wrong fast. Print it, copy paste it into your SQL client, and execute it yourself.

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong SQL - heres is the new one @Konerak

Comment: @loosebruce: SQL injection. Read about it

Comment: Does the query work when you run it via phpmyadmin/mysql client/heidisql etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query

```
$result = $db->query("
  SELECT * FROM contact 
  WHERE first_name LIKE \"%$search%\" 
  OR second_name LIKE \"%$search%\" 
  OR company_name LIKE \"%$search%\" 
  OR email LIKE \"%$search%\" 
  GROUP BY first_name, second_name, company_name, email
");
```

seems to belong to another table. Also, why do you GROUP BY? Maybe, you meant ORDER BY?

Comment: i use groupby to remove duplicate rows returned

Comment: Use Select DISTINCT...  for that.